# jVectorMap on mobile requires 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I've been using jVectorMap quite successfully-- it's a wonderful package for displaying interactive maps!

In this case, I only want some regions to be selectable, and there doesn't seem to be an option to set regions active/inactive.  So instead, I set "regionsSelectable=false", and then set "selectedRegions" to the ones I want active.

This works fine (showing the correct hover attributes, etc. for "active" regions only)-- with one exception, in iOS.  There, it takes two "clicks" (touches) for the "onRegionClick" handler to get invoked.  On the first click, the "selectedHover" attributes are set correctly, but "handleRegion" never gets called.  A second click, and "handleRegion" is called.

Initialization code looks like:

```
map = new jvm.WorldMap({
    container: $('#mapdiv'),
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    regionsSelectable: false,
    regionStyle: {
        initial: { fill: '#0086d0' },
        hover: { "fill-opacity": 1.0 },
        selected: { fill: '#003a6a' },
        selectedHover: { fill: '#ff7a00' }
    },
    onRegionClick: handleRegion,
    selectedRegions:["CN","RU","US"],
    ...
});

function handleRegion(e,cc) {
    alert("cc="+cc);
    ...
}
```

What is needed is either a way to "activate" only a few regions, or a way around this two-click problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit outdated question, but here is a hack around iOS issue for others like me who bumped to this question while searching for some hack around this.

As you already noted, iPad/iPhone are emulating hover with first "tap" .. and click with second "tap".

So to fix this ackward behavior we will do following (example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtuezdtc/))

```
var lastCode = "";
var iOS = /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test( navigator.userAgent );
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
     map: 'world_mill_en',
     backgroundColor: 'green',
     normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
     regionsSelectable: true,
     regionsSelectableOne: true,
     zoomOnScroll: true,
     zoomButtons: true,
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: "white",
                "fill-opacity": 1,
                stroke: "none",
                "stroke-width": 0,
                "stroke-opacity": 1
            },
            hover: {
                fill: "white",
                "fill-opacity": 1
            },
            selected: {
                fill: "#EC6602",
                "fill-opacity": 1
            },
            selectedHover: {
                fill: "#EC6602",
                "fill-opacity": 1
            }
        },


    onRegionClick: function(e, country){
        if (lastCode && lastCode == country) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        var map = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
        $("#world-map").vectorMap("set", "focus", country);
        map.setScale(2);

        if(country=="US" || country=="RU") {
            map.setScale(1);  
        }
        lastCode = country;
    },
    onRegionLabelShow: function (e, el, country) {
        if (iOS) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var map = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
            if (lastCode) {
                map.regions[lastCode].element.setSelected(false);
            }
            map.regions[country].element.setSelected(true);
            $("#world-map").vectorMap("set", "focus", country);
            map.setScale(2);

            if(country=="US" || country=="RU") {
                map.setScale(1);  
            }
            lastCode = country;
        }
    },
     markers: [{
         latLng: [37.7833, -122.4167],
         name: 'San Francisco'
     }]
 });
```

In short words, we are overwriting onRegionLabelShow functionality with custom behavior (only for the iOS devices). Basically we are preventing the tooltip from showing and instead of that we are selecting the hovered (tapped) ccountry, focusing it and storing it's code in global variable.

On second tap we are detecting if the country has changed by comparing current code with last value and in that case un-selecting previously selected country and selecting new one.

It should be fairly easy to adapt the resolution to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

actually, you should check onRegionTipShow:

```
...
handleIOSClick = function (e, el, code) {
        if (istouch) {
            var mapObject = $(map).vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
            map.regions[code].element.setSelected(true);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    CreateMap = function () {
        if (typeof $(map) !== 'undefined'){
            $(map).width(700);
            $(map).height(400);
            mapObject = $(map).vectorMap({
                map: 'us_lcc_en',
                onRegionClick: regionClicked,
                onRegionTipShow: handleIOSClick,
                backgroundColor: "inherit",
                regionStyle: {
                    initial: {
                        fill: '#477294'
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    },
...
```